# careers invitation link doesn't open

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have been invited by stackoverflow for carreers 2.0 site due to my good answers/questions in java tag but when i click the link i got this error

[image]

is this a server outage or something like that ?

Comment: ok it is working now , may be it was something temporary , thanks any way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.  Sorry about that.  Should be fixed now.